# Efficient numerical way to "damp"/"filter" an array depending on the actual value

Tags: arrays, filter

I have an array of values, for the sake of simplicity let's assume it's just linearly increasing from 0 to 5 over e.g. 100 values. Now I want to filter that array such that I have a Gaussian-like envelope around a certain value (e.g. around 2.5) with which I multiply the original array (I want only a certain range around that value of 2.5 to be affected).

One approach would be to calculate/identify first the location of that specific value, and then use a Gaussian which has its central point (its peak) at that location. Due to a very large array, I do not really want to do that. Would be a more efficient way, using just that specific value (2.5 in the above example), and thus just having an additional multiplication (or a few) to get a similar effect possible? How would that look like?

(Hope that description was clear...?)

I could simple use an if-statement to check how close